# OpenShift in Azure, nodes fail to start with "instance not found"

Tags: azure, openshift

I have installed OpenShift OCP 3.7 on five RedHat virtual machines in Azure using the "advanced installation" option with Ansible. Everything works fine until trying to set cloud-provider to azure. After that, the nodes fail to start with messages like the following:

```
azure_instances.go:34] error: az.NodeAddresses, az.getIPForMachine(foo-0.bar.baz.com), err=instance not found
cloud_request_manager.go:105] Node addresses from cloud provider for node "foo-0.bar.baz.com" not collected
```

The names of the virtual machines in Azure are `foo-0` through `foo-4`, but the node names in OpenShift are the fully qualified domain names, like `foo-0.bar.baz.com`, at least that is what `oc get nodes` shows. It seems to me that OpenShift is asking Azure for information using the FQDN, which Azure cannot find.

My question is if I have to use only the hostname, e.g., `foo-0`, as OpenShift node name and not the FQDN to be able to connect OpenShift to Azure?

If that is the case, how do I configure the OpenShift installation to use "short" node names, without the domain name?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to the problem.

In the Ansible inventory where you define the environment you're setting up, add the `openshift_hostname` variable with the short name you want to use as node name to each host. For example, in the YAML inventory we use:

```
OSEv3:
  ...
  children:
    nodes:
      hosts:
        foo-0:
          openshift_hostname: foo-0
          openshift_schedulable: false
          first_master: true
        foo-1:
          openshift_hostname: foo-1
          openshift_schedulable: false
        foo-2:
          openshift_hostname: foo-2
          openshift_schedulable: false
        foo-3:
          openshift_hostname: foo-3
          openshift_node_labels: {'region': 'infra', 'zone': 'default'}
        foo-4:
          openshift_hostname: foo-4
          openshift_node_labels: {'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'default'}
    ...
```

It seems that without `openshift_hostname`, the OpenShift installation will use a DNS lookup using the node host name, e.g., `foo-0`, and use the result as node name. In our case, we got back the fully qualified domain name, e.g., `foo-0.bar.baz.com`, which was then used as node name.